# Can't run Roboletric on windows: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.Looper.<init>(boolean)

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I want to add support for unit tests on an existing Android Studio 1.1 project. I followed [this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) tutorial but I am getting the error:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.Looper.<init>(boolean)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:228)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at ...
```

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/le1oJKpIW9Q) solution but that only applies to mac, and I can't find a similar way to do it in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out. In my maven settings.xml I added (as specified in [maven site](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)):

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

After remove it, Roboletric worked fine.